# MySQL Workbench Error Code 1054 for Invalid Column Even When I Have the Corresponding Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science

I am having an issue with MySQL Community Server Workbench. I input this command on MySQL File Queries and get this error

Command:

```
use CIA_DATA;

SELECT * FROM new_table;

SELECT Country, GDP, Electricity;
FROM new_table;
WHERE GDP < 4000;
ORDER BY Electricity;

select now(); database();
```

Error:
22:03:14 SELECT Country, GDP, Electricity LIMIT 0, 50000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Country' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Please let me know what mistakes I have made. Keep in mind that my Result Grid has these field names/columns:
Water, Sanitation, GDP, Life, Underweight, Literacy, Electricity, Country

Thanks

Comment: Remove 3 semicolons.

Comment: Thanks, which semicolons need to be deleted?

Comment: You should review basic sql syntax - in short every statement needs to be terminated (not every line) and every selected item needs to be separated by a comma and every statement needs a verb (database(); does not) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the short comment, but I used my tablet and hate virtual keyboards.

Semicolons separate instructions. So you have to rewrite the code to:

```
SELECT Country, GDP, Electricity
FROM new_table
WHERE GDP < 4000
ORDER BY Electricity;

select now(), database();
```

Comment: After making the changes, I got another error, do you have a solution? Here is the error log: 

19:59:15 database() Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database()' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Have you replaced the semicolon behind `select now()`?